# Preprocessor adding extra (unwanted) space under last div/footer

Tags: css

Inspite of setting all margins and padding to 0, I'm suddenly finding that processing my html & css using a **Prepros**, is adding extra (unwanted) space under my last item eg. footer. While running the same html & css directly from Notepad++, does not do this (thankfully). Can someone please explain why this is happening since I will eventually be using Prepos and running from a local host. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf=8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

  <body>


            <header>header
            </header>

            <div class="wrapper">wrapper1
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">wrapper2
            </div>

            <footer>footer
            </footer>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
html{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 3px solid green;
}

body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
border: 3px solid lightblue;
height: 100vh;
}


header{
flex: 1;
height: 50%;
background-color: red;
border: 3px solid black;
}

.wrapper{
flex: 1;
height: 20%;
background-color: blue;
border: 3px solid black;
}

footer{
height: 5%;
position: absolute:
bottom: 0;
background-color: orange;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Here are images of the same code running, first from file:/// and the other from localhost:

[image]

[image]

(edit: addition)Is it possible that this has something to do with the **prepros.cfg** file that gets added by **Prepros**? I am also using a trial version of Prepros - could this be causing the issue? Would appreciate any clarification on this matter. NOTE: Above is the discrepancy in every browser i tried it on (Chrome, Firefox and Opera).

Comment: i copied your code but not able to see any issue. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/Leo_the_lion/arxdLmyh/

Comment: maybe tha'ts because you have declared your body `height: 100vh;` try increasing your height

Comment: @Leothelion: yes, neither is my file:/// creating any issues. i need to know why Prepros is adding space.

Comment: @sanojlawrence: This happens at all the heights i've tried (and also if i omit height)

Comment: can you please share code which is adding space?

Comment: @Leothelion: it is the same code: but processed through Prepros. which incidentally adds a prepros.cfg to the files.